# selecting more than 1 table to get content from [php/Mysql]

Tags: php, mysql, function

i want to get the latest threads/messages
i made my code
then
i made function
that calls the code to show last messages in specific board
it works great
now 
i want to get latest messages from 2 boards or more in the same function
this is the part that chooses the board

```
     AND b.id_board = t.id_board' . (empty($vars) ? '' : '
     AND b.id_board = ' . $vars . ''). '
```

i tried to use
functionname(1.2.3);
but he says no board with id 1.2.3
i tried ("1,2,3")
same
i wish i made it clear for you
i apreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of `b.id_board = ' . $vars . '` you need `b.id_board in (' . $vars . ')`, then $var would be a comma separated list of ids as a string `"1,2,3"`. (leaving all security issues aside :) )